# XDocument not exists

Tags: iphone, .net, xamarin.ios, linq-to-xml

i'm using both

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
```

and there is not `XDocument` Object exits.

and also there is no

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

any idea?
thanks

Comment: Solved! forgot to add the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a reference to System.Xml.Linq, just like you would need in Visual Studio.

I think .Net 4.0 projects in Visual Studio come with that dll referenced by default, and MonoDevelop doesn't.